# How to find and remove a long pattern in text files using linux sed with regex

Tags: regex, sed

I'm parsing a lot of bibtex files into R for some data analysis. However the abstracts cause problems on a regular basis and I want to remove them beforehand using `sed`.

I have found `sed 's/Abstract\s\=\s[{][{]//' < file.bib`

to sucessfully remove the Abstract entry and

`sed 's/[}][}]\,//' < file.bib` to remove the closing parenthesis and the comma.

However, I was not able to combine the two in any way to remove everything in between as well. For example by trying:

```
sed 's/^Abstract\s\=\s[{][{][\s\S]*[}][}]\,$//' < file.bib
```

This is what a bibtex reference looks like:

```
@article{ ISI:000072671200001,
Author = {Edmondson, A and Moingeon, B},
Title = {{From organizational learning to the learning organization}},
Journal = {{MANAGEMENT LEARNING}},
Year = {{1998}},
Volume = {{29}},
Number = {{1}},
Pages = {{5-20}},
Month = {{MAR}},
Abstract = {{This article reviews theories of organizational learning and presents a
   framework with which to organize the literature. We argue that unit of
   analysis provides one critical distinction in the organizational
   learning literature and research objective provides another. The
   resulting two-by-two matrix contains four categories of research, which
   we have called: (2) residues (organizations as residues of past
   learning); (2) communities (organizations as collections of individuals
   who can learn and develop); (3) participation (organizational
   improvement gained through intelligent activity of individual members),
   and (4) accountability (organizational improvement gained through
   developing individuals' mental models). We also propose a distinction
   between the terms organizational learning and the learning organization.
   Our subsequent analysis identifies relationships between disparate parts
   of the literature and shows that these relationships point to individual
   mental models as a critical source of leverage for creating learning
   organizations. A brief discussion of the work of two of the most visible
   researchers in this field, Peter Senge and Chris Argyris, provides
   additional support for this type of change strategy.}},
DOI = {{10.1177/1350507698291001}},
ISSN = {{1350-5076}},
Unique-ID = {{ISI:000072671200001}},
}
```

And this is how I would like it to look like:

```
@article{ ISI:000072671200001,
Author = {Edmondson, A and Moingeon, B},
Title = {{From organizational learning to the learning organization}},
Journal = {{MANAGEMENT LEARNING}},
Year = {{1998}},
Volume = {{29}},
Number = {{1}},
Pages = {{5-20}},
Month = {{MAR}},
DOI = {{10.1177/1350507698291001}},
ISSN = {{1350-5076}},
Unique-ID = {{ISI:000072671200001}},
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try piping the sed commands sequentially to each other. Something like this:

```
sed 's/Abstract\s\=\s[{][{]//' < file.bib | sed 's/[}][}]\,//'
```

You could also try using an OR Regex operator in your pattern like:

```
sed 's/Abstract\s\=\s[{][{]|[}][}]\,//' < file.bib
```

Either of those should work. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^Abstract = {{/,/.*}},$/d' file
```

This uses a range operator `,` which combined with the delete command `d` deletes lines starting with `Abstract = {{` through to a line ending `}},`.